# High performance mass short string search in Python

Tags: python, string, search

The Problem: A large static list of strings is provided as `A`, A long string is provided as `B`, strings in `A` are all very short (a keywords list), I want to check if every string in `A` is a sub-string of `B` and get them.

Now I use a simple loop like:

```
result = []
for word in A:
    if word in B:
        result.append(word)
```

But it's crazy slow when A contains ~500,000 or more items.

Is there any library or algorithm that fits this problem? I've tried my best to search but no luck.

Thank you!

Comment: Just a theory - what if you try using `B.find(word)` instead of `if word in B`? I believe `in` is fast if the substring is really in `B`, but it will get much slower if it's not a substring. `find` might be faster.

Comment: @birryree Thanks for the comment, but in my tests using a `B.find(word)` instead of `word in B` did not make any effort in performance :(

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your problem is large enough that you probably need to hit it with the algorithm bat.

Take a look into the [Aho-Corasick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_string_matching_algorithm) Algorithm.  Your problem statement is a paraphrase of the problem that this algorithm tackles.

Also, look into the work by Nicholas Lehuen with his [PyTST](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytst/) package.

There are also references in a related Stack Overflow message that mention other algorithms such as Rabin-Karp: [Algorithm for linear pattern matching?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250399/algorithm-for-linear-pattern-matching)

Comment: +1 -- this is the answer. I thought of a [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie)-based approach, but this is even better.

Comment: Thank you so much that I've got it to work perfectly, here is the my test result:`2012-01-13 11:48:07.632212 Importing test cases` `2012-01-13 11:48:17.191975 Scaning using in` `2012-01-13 11:48:47.750070 Scan completed` `2012-01-13 11:48:47.752614 TSTing` `2012-01-13 11:48:56.780503 Scaning using tst` `2012-01-13 11:48:56.798033 Scan completed`

Answer (score 3):

Depending on how long your long string is, it may be worth it to do something like this:

```
ls = 'my long string of stuff'
#Generate all possible substrings of ls, keeping only uniques
x = set([ls[p:y] for p in range(0, len(ls)+1) for y in range(p+1, len(ls)+1)])

result = []
for word in A:
    if word in x:
        result.append(word)
```

Obviously if your long string is very, very long then this also becomes too slow, but it should be faster for any string under a few hundred characters.

Comment: the OP pointed out a very important detail here: he's parsing Chinese characters. Therefore `ls='mylongstringofstuff'`, and won't map to a set between combinations of the `ls`'s indexes very usefully.

Comment: @Droogans I posted this before he added that, but I still don't see the problem. Let `ls = '解析するためにいくつかの文字' as a random example of (Japanese) characters - the above still (almost) works (there's actually a small bug in what I've written that I'm trying to fix, but I think the idea is still fine). Edit: Bug should be fixed.

Comment: I apologize. If you're compiling your examples using kanji characters with no spaces, and are getting useful results, then I must not be understanding your code (or the problem) as clearly as I should.

Comment: I was thinking of something along these lines, but only generating substrings of length up to the longest element of `A`.

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky Ah yes, that might be a good optimization to make.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this would be any quicker, but it's a lot more pythonic:

```
result = [x for x in A if x in B]
```

Comment: Yes it's more pythonic, but no quicker will happen :(

Comment: (+1) I don't think that there's a better solution.  (Other than using a performance-minded language, like C).

Answer (score 1):

Pack up all the individual words of `B` into a new list, consisting of the original string split by `' '`. Then, for each element in `B`, test for membership against each element of `A`. If you find one (or more), delete it/them from `A`, and quit as soon as `A` is empty.

It seems like your approach will blaze through 500,000 candidates without an opt-out set in place.

Comment: Sorry I did not make it clear, that the strings are in Chinese, so words are not separated by spaces. I will have to do much more work to find out "all the individual words of `B`".

Comment: @FelixYan my last comment should then be my only useful advice to you; find a way to slim down your list of candidates as you comb through `B`. One less member in the outer `for` loop using `A` will speed up your search times, no matter how you go about doing it.

Answer (score 1):

Assume you has all keywords of the same length (later you could extend this algo for different lengths)

I could suggest next:

1. precalculate some hash for each keyword (for example xor hash):

   ```
   hash256 = reduce(int.__xor__, map(ord, keyword))
   ```
2. create a dictionary where key is a hash, and value list of corresponding keywords
3. save keyword length

   ```
   curr_keyword = []
   for x in B:
     if len(curr_keyword) == keyword_length:
        hash256 = reduce(int.__xor__, map(ord, curr_keyword))
        if hash256 in dictionary_of_hashed:
           #search in list

     curr_keyword.append(x)
     curr_keyword = curr_keyword[1:]
   ```

Something like this